# Accessing global variables in chrome extension when using injecting script to the page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

After injecting an extension's code into a website, is there a way to get to the original site's variables on the `window`?

As it seems, content-script only works for external windows and pop-ups (where the "isolated world" is the same one as of the extension itself) and does not work in the case I mentioned above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script)

Comment: See also [JS get varible defined in script tag (Google Extension)](//stackoverflow.com/a/46941198)